# Why do i need comparable interface instead of creating my custom made method in java

Tags: java, interface

`Comparable` is an interface that can be implemented into a class, what I cannot understand is that why do I need to implement the interface in order to use `Arrays.sort` in my class. I can call the `Arrays.sort` without having to implement the interface `Comparable` into my class.

Moreover, an interface offers an empty method anyways so that I can specify my own operation. I have read the other answers about comparable and they all say that the reason is to make my coding easier. how is that easier the `compareTo` is just an empty code that I have to define, so how is that helping anyway, I could define my own code and name it anything I want.

I am quite sure there is a good reason behind it. however, I cannot understand it, and it is really disturbing me, can someone explain it to me with examples "not code example". In a very simple English please, and why is important and how is it saving me time. Thanks, in advance

Comment: *I can call the Arrays.sort without having to implement the interface comparable into my class*: no, you can't. Do it, and you'll see. How would the sort() method compare elements of the array if you don't tell it how to do it? That's what Comparable is for. Just as if I ask you to sort books. How can you know if you mst sort them by height, by their author, by their title, or by the number of pages?

Comment: The reason why you need to implement an interface is because the Arrays.Sort has to know which method has to be called to execute the compare, that method is the one defined in the interface.

Comment: Still not clear, an interface is just a contract that I sign, however, the methods that are declared are empty so how can it do anything at all. I am the one who is defining that method after I implement it in my class, i mean i could have called it anything if i want, so what exactly an empty method can do or decide anything. here is where I am really getting confused.

Comment: `Arrays.sort` relies on the `compareTo` method to do its sorting. But a class is normally not required to implement a `compareTo` method. So, instead, the `Arrays.sort` only accepts objects from classes that implement Comparable. Since implementing an interface requires you to implement all its methods, the sort function can now be certain that the object you pass will have a `compareTo` method, and can safely call it.

Comment: @salimALmughairi _Declaring_ in this sense means: Defining name and parameters (also called signature). _Defining_ means writing the methods body (also called implementing). `Array.sort` does not call the interface's method (which is impossible because interfaces cannot be instantiated) but the code written by you when you implemented the methods body. But name and signature are exactly as declared by the interface: That is the contract you signed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take these numbers as an example: 4, 7, 2, 7, 42, 3, 4 ,9 , and 5.

Say I ask you to sort them. How would you do it? Would you sort them in ascending order, descending order, or using some other method.

Then answer is, you wouldn't know how to sort them because I didn't provide you with enough information.

`Arrays.sort` is in a similar unknowing position. You want to ask it to sort something for you, but simply put, `Arrays.sort` doesn't *know* how to sort it. You have to explain to `Arrays.sort` how you want the array sorted. And the way you explain this to `Arrays.sort` is to implement the `Comparable` interface.

As for how this design saves you time. Well, it does so in a subtle way: If you implement `Comparable`, then you automatically get to use any method (think algorithm) which knows how to work with `Comparable`. The same applies for implementing other interfaces.

Comment: thanks, however, your answer was not complete to me, i still find it difficult to understand how would a function in another class would force a function in yet another class to understand something and there is no clear explanation as how these two classes related to each other.  but it is more clear then any other answer here, it gave me a kick start if you like. thanks anyway.

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have used the word _understand_. Lets use the steering wheel of a car as an example. In all cars the steering wheel provides the same _interface_: it allows the driver to steer the car. However, there are multiple _implementations_ of a steering wheel: no power steering, (traditional) power steering, and electrical power steering. To stretch the analogy, to the driver the _implementation_ doesn't matter. All that matters is that the _interface_, the way a steering wheel is used, is the same. `Arrays.sort` expects a certain behavior, but doesn't care how it's implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The `public static void sort(Object[] a)` method specified in the Javadoc that all objects must implement the `Comparable` interface. That is assumed in the implementation, where you can find the next line.

```
Comparable pivot = (Comparable) a[start];
```

If your elements don't implement comparable, that will produce a runtime exception.

The other `sort` methods are either for types that are intrinsically comparable (for example, primitive types) or require you to provide a `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have `Arrays.sort((T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c))` method which accepts an explicit `Comparator`, you wouldn't want to define an inline `Comparator` or create a special `Comparator` class to keep your code compact and readable.

Rest is your choice. You have both the options, choose what suits you.